# Selenium testng saucelabs maven Error

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng, saucelabs

Im trying to run a test using selenium testng on Saucelabs. Im getting an error and cant seem to figure it out!

I`ve tried different versions for the Surefire plugin , testng but cant seem to resolve this.
Here the maven stack trace . Any help is much appreciated

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.
14:test (default-test) on project functional: Execution default-test of goal org
.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14:test failed: There was an error
 in the forked process
[ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException: java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:340)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1004)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.ja
va:178)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXml
TestSuite.java:92)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider
.java:96)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2
(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke
(ProviderFactory.java:158)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(Provi
derFactory.java:86)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(Fork
edBooter.java:153)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:
95)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.xmlListeners(TestNGContentHandler
.java:352)
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.endElement(TestNGContentHandler.j
ava:700)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endEleme
nt(AbstractSAXParser.java:606)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endNamesp
aceScope(XMLDTDValidator.java:2054)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEnd
Element(XMLDTDValidator.java:2005)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElemen
t(XMLDTDValidator.java:879)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1742)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2900)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(X
MLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(X
ML11Configuration.java:835)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(X
ML11Configuration.java:764)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.
java:123)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Ab
stractSAXParser.java:1210)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.p
arse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParser
Impl.java:302)
[ERROR] at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:17)
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:10)
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:172)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:310)
[ERROR] ... 13 more
```

Comment: can you share the surefire plugin config

Comment: I've managed to resolved it. Had incorrectly named test files.